# How do I reset the ALLOWNONE status of a wxDatePickerCtrl?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, wxpython, wxformbuilder

The code below uses sqlalchemy to check an sqlite3 mapped table(Ppe) for dates.
It then uses these dates to populate a field on a wxForm on a comboBox event.

```
def refresh_ppe( self, event ):
        selected_user = str(self.m_comboBox31.GetValue())
        session = start_session()
        updater = session.query(Ppe).filter(Ppe.name == selected_user).first()
        new_date = updater.ear_defenders
        try:
            self.m_datePicker23.SetValue(_pydate2wxdate(new_date))
        except AssertionError:
            self.m_datePicker23.SetValue(None)
```

[Image of control in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBXPa.png)

What I'm trying to do is when I repopulate the table with an entry with a Null date for Ear Defenders (because they haven't been issued them) that it resets the ALLOWNONE state of the DatePickerCtrl and clears the checkbox.

I have tried self.m_panel1681.Refresh() (the parent panel) and also tried hiding and showing the panel and the DatePickerCtrl.

Any help would be greatfully recieved.

Thanks
Paul.

Answer (score 1):

The `wxDP_ALLOWNONE` is a flag so it shouldn't be losing that unless it is explicitly removed.  I assume that what you mean is the visual state of the widget and what is done for that is up to the native control and how it chooses to represent the current value. The usual pattern for things like this in wxWidgets is to use an invalid object of the given type to represent empty, null, default, etc.  So I would try using `self.m_datePicker23.SetValue(wx.DefaultDateTime)`.